# HTML not storing jquery values

Tags: html, jquery

I have this issue where i want to store the product name and product price in data variables in a jquery, however the html code doesn't seem to store the values. Here is the html code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-5">                    
                    <div class="product-item">                      
                          <figure>
                            <img src="images/paw/All_3.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                          </figure>
                        <div class="px-4" data-name="Paw Necklace" data-price="150">
                            <h3 class="product-name">Glow in the dark Paw necklace</h3>
                            <p class="product-price">&#82; 150</p>
                            <div>
                              <form class="add-to-cart" action="cart.html" method="post">
                                        <div>
                                            <label for="qty-1">Quantity</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="qty-1" id="qty-1" class="qty" value="1" />
                                        </div>
                                        <p><input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn" /></p>
                                </form>
                            </div>                      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

And the section from the jquery:

```
handleAddToCartForm: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.$formAddToCart.each(function() {
                var $form = $( this );
                var $product = $form.parent();
                var price = self._convertString( $product.data( "price" ) );
                var name =  $product.data( "name" );
                
                $form.on( "submit", function() {
                    var qty = self._convertString( $form.find( ".qty" ).val() );
                    var subTotal = qty * price;
                    var total = self._convertString( self.storage.getItem( self.total ) );
                    var sTotal = total + subTotal;
                    self.storage.setItem( self.total, sTotal );
                    self._addToCart({
                        product: name,
                        price: price,
                        qty: qty
                    });
                    var shipping = self._convertString( self.storage.getItem( self.shippingRates ) );
                    var shippingRates = self._calculateShipping( qty );
                    var totalShipping = shipping + shippingRates;
                    
                    self.storage.setItem( self.shippingRates, totalShipping );
                });
            });
        },
```

Comment: you can use window local storage instead.

Answer (score 1):

The extra `<div>` above the form fixed my issue. I just removed it